# How to create only one game with a boolean field true for each provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

The models I have:

**Category:**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :providers, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end
```

**Provider:**

```
class Provider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end
```

**Categorization:**

```
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :provider
  has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :games
end
```

**Game:**

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categorization
end
```

The `games` table has `most_popular` field that is boolean. I need that only one game for each provider could have that boolean field set to true. If I had to make that only one game could have a boolean field = true, I would do smth. like this:

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categorization

  validate :only_one_most_popular_game
  scope :most_popular, -> { where(most_popular: true) }

  protected

  def only_one_most_popular_game
    return unless most_popular?

    matches = Game.most_popular
    if persisted?
      matches = matches.where('id != ?', id)
    end
    if matches.exists?
      errors.add(:most_popular, 'Can\'t have another most popular game.')
    end
  end
end
```

So, what is the best way to solve this issue? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to look at all `games`, you only want to look at the ones for that categorization.

```
def only_one_most_popular_game
  return unless most_popular?
  if categorization.games.most_popular.where('id != ?', id).first
    errors.add(:most_popular, 'Can\'t have another most popular game.')
  end
end
```

EDIT

You can also specify

```
class Provider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :games, through: :categories
```

(above requires Rails 3.1 or later)

Which will let you do...

```
if categorization.provider.games.most_popular.where('games.id != ?', id).first
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Even for the game with `categorization_id` that doesn't have `most_popular = true`, the validation doesn't pass.

Comment: Also, this code refers to categorization, but I need the provider. Provider's id is stored in categorization table.

Comment: Your code says `Categorization` is `belongs_to :provider`.  Are you saying you want only one "most popular" across ALL categorizations?

Comment: I need only one most_popular for each provider. Maybe I should refactor the model relations?

Comment: My edit should handle the validation.  Rails 3.1 allows nested `has_many` so it's possible to access all games for a provider

Comment: "doesn't work" means you have an error?  Or it just lets the validation pass?

Comment: I mean, the validation doesn't path, when I set `most_popular` to true, the validation fails, in case I already have any game with `most_popular == true`

Comment: Ah, yes, the test is wrong!  The  `if` expression always returns something, even if it's an empty relation set.  We need to do `first` to get the first record (which will be nil if the relation is empty).  See my new edit

Comment: Now it gives me an error, when I update a game: `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...der_id" = $1 AND "games"."most_popular" = $2 AND (id != 4) O... ^ : SELECT "games".* FROM "games" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "games"."categorization_id" = "categorizations"."id" WHERE "categorizations"."provider_id" = $1 AND "games"."most_popular" = $2 AND (id != 4) ORDER BY "games"."id" ASC LIMIT $3`